# Как узнать валюту страны, в которой находится пользователь?

Tags: android, google-maps-api, геолокация

Как можно узнать валюту той страны, в которой на данный момент находится пользователь Android-приложения? Предполагается, что пользователь часто путешествует и меняет страну. Подскажите какой-нибудь сервис с открытым API.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Решение с конца:
https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Currency.html
Класс который отдает код валюты, символ и т.п. Делается из локали:

```
Currency currency = Currency.getInstance(locale);
```

Локаль можно сделать из координат:

```
Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(ctx, Locale.getDefault());
    List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);
    if (addresses.size() > 0) {
        Address address = addresses.get(0);
        regionCode = address.getCountryCode();
    }
```

Статья от первоисточника: https://developer.android.com/training/location/display-address.html

regionCode  должен содержать 2х символьный код, например 'RU','US','DE'.

Из этого кода и делаем локаль:

```
Locale whereMI = new Locale(regionCode);
```

Мои извинения за бессвязность кода, надрал из разных проектов по частям.

П.С. Еще вместо GPS для получения кода страны можно использовать [ip-api.com/json](http://ip-api.com/json) . С известными оговорками конечно.

Comment: Главное что подсказали где искать) Спасибо)